# Count values for multiple columns

Tags: powerquery

In Power Query, how is the first table transformed into the second? In the second table the categorical values are counted for every column. The set of values for every column is limited to: Strongly agree, Agree, Neutral, Disagree, Strongly disagree.

| Question A | Question B | Question C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly disagree | Agree | Neutral |
| Disagree | Strongly disagree | Strongly agree |
| Agree | Agree | Neutral |
| Neutral | Strongly agree | Neutral |
| Strongly agree | Agree | Strongly disagree |
| Disagree | Strongly disagree | Strongly agree |

In to this:

| Agree, Disagree | Question A | Question B | Question C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly agree | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Agree | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Neutral | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Disagree | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Strongly disagree | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery:  Add column .. index column. Click select the index then right click Unpivot other columns. Right click and remove the index column. Right click and duplicate the value column. Click select the Attribute column, transform .. pivot column ... and choose value-copy as the values column and in advanced options, count all

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Question A", type text}, {"Question B", type text}, {"Question C", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Index"}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", "Value - Copy"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value - Copy", List.Count)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

from there, manually sort the output, or create some sort of merge or if/then to add a sort key

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCi4pys9Lz6lUSMksTkwvSk1V0lFyhNJ+qaUlRYk5SrE60UouCGlsWuBiEAGQDkc8psHYGBpRlWFIOuJ0AhlujAUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Question A" = _t, #"Question B" = _t, #"Question C" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Question A", type text}, {"Question B", type text}, {"Question C", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Count", List.Sum),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Question A", "Question B", "Question C"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```