# Value replacement in all columns based on condition

Tags: powerquery

There is a table like this. How can I change all the values where the column "Agree, Disagree" is in "Disagree" of "Strongly disagree" to negative numbers?

It should be done without referring to the column names. The replacements to negative numbers should be applied to all columns, except the "Agree, Disagree" column.

| Agree, Disagree | Question A | Question B | Question C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly agree | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Agree | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Neutral | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Disagree | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Strongly disagree | 1 | 2 | 1 |

The outcome should be:

| Agree, Disagree | Question A | Question B | Question C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly agree | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Agree | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Neutral | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Disagree | -2 | 0 | 0 |
| Strongly disagree | -1 | -2 | -1 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCi4pys9Lz6lUSEwvSk1VUNJRMoQTRkqxOtFKjigSxiDCACzhl1paUpSYA5cyAMuDpVwyi+HmGcHlINrgNqYgKTKEqzRUio0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Agree, Disagree" = _t, #"Question A" = _t, #"Question B" = _t, #"Question C" = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Agree, Disagree"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    a = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([#"Agree, Disagree"] <> "Disagree " and [#"Agree, Disagree"] <> "Strongly disagree ")),
    Custom1 = #"Changed Type",
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Custom1, each ([#"Agree, Disagree"] = "Disagree " or [#"Agree, Disagree"] = "Strongly disagree ")),
    #"Multiplied Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Value", each _ * -1, type number}}),
    Custom2 = Table.Combine({#"Multiplied Column",a}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Custom2, List.Distinct(Custom2[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Upvoted David for correct answer to this specific question, but that's not what you probably want to do, so I added my own answer

Answer (score 1):

So, to go back to your last question [Count values for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347740/count-values-for-multiple-columns) , do both transformations at once. Otherwise the answer to this question is duplicating steps you don't need from the last question

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each if [Value]="Disagree" or [Value]="Strongly disagree" then -1 else 1),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]