# Sort columns based on their sum

Tags: powerquery

There is a table like this:

| Agree, Disagree | Question A | Question B | Question C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly agree | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| Agree | 6 | 3 | 2 |
| Neutral | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Disagree | -2 | 0 | 0 |
| Strongly disagree | -1 | -2 | -1 |

How can the columns (except for column "Agree, Disagree") be sorted based on there sum?

The references to the columns should NOT be by name (all, but the "Agree, Disagree" column). The columns with the highest value, go to the right, the lowest to the left. Independent from the number of columns.

The result should be the following order of columns:

"Agree, Disagree", "Question B" (5), "Question C" (6), "Question A" (9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular question, you can do this:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Agree, Disagree"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
Sort = Table.ReorderColumns(Source,List.Combine({{Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}},Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Sum", Order.Ascending}})[Attribute]}))
in Sort
```

[image]

That said, each of your last 3 questions requires pivoting and unpivoting, which should all be done at once rather the pivot/unpivot/pivot/unpivot to answer each of your questions in sequence.  To do all your 3 questions [Sort columns based on their sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377358/sort-columns-based-on-their-sum)
[Value replacement in all columns based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374640/value-replacement-in-all-columns-based-on-condition) [Count values for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347740/count-values-for-multiple-columns)  at once you could do this, image below, from original question to current requirement

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each if [Value]="Disagree" or [Value]="Strongly disagree" then -1 else 1),
#"Sorted" = Table.Sort(Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Attribute"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Custom]), type number}}),{{"Sum", Order.Descending}})[Attribute],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom", List.Sum),
ReSort = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",List.Combine({{Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"){0}},#"Sorted"}))
in  ReSort
```

[image]